# Visual Studio design view contains yellow warning icons?

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, xaml

I have created a WPF project in Visual Studio which contains a `MainWindow`. This "imports" other user controls via XAML. The `MainWindow` is shown with warning icons and the following text. Unfortunately I don't have the English translation but it means something like this:

> This document contains one or more controls which have been changed.
> Rebuild the project to show the changes in the design view.

[image]

Rebuilding the complete solution does not help. However these warnings do not have any effect.

How can I get rid of these warnings?

Comment: This happened to me in Visual Studio when I included a view1 inside view2 when view1 had its datacontext set to self.   I removed the DataContext line and went through the steps of clearing the bin and obj files and then doing the steps Robert provided and it went away permanently.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I have tried Asryaels solution which is as follows:

1. Cleaning
2. Rebuilding
3. Saving all documents
4. Closing Visual Studio
5. Starting Visual Studio
6. Cleaning
7. Rebuilding

Comment: If the user control's are in a separate project, I found cleaning & rebuilding the project effective.

Comment: As @Chuck Savage said, I had the controls in separate project, and just cleaning & rebuilding (I did the whole solution, which included the project with the controls) sufficed. No restarting of VS (2015) was needed.

Comment: Wow. We still have to do this song and dance in VS2015 in the year 2017. What's with MS and their shoddy software? Gee, I wonder why WPF and Blend never caught on.

Comment: Still happening even now! Tried 10 different things then restarted visual studio...

Comment: And in VS2019 also

Answer (score 0):

When encountering the same problem, closing the solution, deleting the Debug and the Release folders in /bin and restarting the solution seems to have helped.

Answer (score 0):

I tried Asryaels solution, but it did not work for me.

Did you switch your platform target? This happened to me when I had project under Platform target: Any CPU and switched to x64. When I switch back to Any CPU warning does not show anymore and control works properly.

If you did switch platform target go to Configuration manager and create a new Active solution platform and for your project set Debug/Release to your project's current platform target. Worked for me.

Comment: I have the same issue. It seems like whenever you pick x64 as platform target on any profile the warning messages just appear. Can't find a way to fix it except changing to Any CPU.

Answer (score 0):

This happens when the control within the ContentControl changes. You have to rebuild the solution to "update" the content within ContentControl.

```
<ContentControl Grid.Row="0">
    <view:View_UserControl_TitleBar/>
</ContentControl>
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. The OP specifically stated in the question that rebuilding the solution does not help.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had a User Control Library project that had errors during compilation.
But those error didn't showed up because I was in Release mode.
So changed to Debug mode and the errors were visible, so I could correct them.
After that, the project built correctly and the yellow marks dissapeared.