# WPF Designer Yellow Warnings on User Controls

Tags: wpf, user-controls, warnings, yellow

VS 2017, WPF

I have a WPF project in which several self made User Controls are defined.
On a window, I have added these controls directly on the window grid as well as on grids on tab items of a tab control.

The project compiles and runs fine.
There are no errors in the XAML view or designer view of the User Controls.
There are no errors in the XAML view of the window.

Here is my problem:
in the designer view of the window, all my User Controls get the yellow triangle warning sign.
How can I find out what these warnings mean and why they are there ?

[image]

Comment: Are the controls in a different project? does it include any nuget package?

Comment: @Lingam: 
Yes, the user controls are in The same projects.
No, the project does not include any Nuget Packages.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Design view of VS 2012 contains yellow warning icons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13910921/design-view-of-vs-2012-contains-yellow-warning-icons)